# Get count of duplicates in a specific field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a list that stays relatively short, but I would like it to function as such:

At the moment I get a list of manifests that have a originRemitStatus of null (i.e. that specific record was never remitted) by using the following in my controller:

```
$unsentManifests = Carrier_Manifest::whereNull('originRemitStatus')->get();
```

I pull them into a simple list, and straight away, you can see there are duplicates of some records. Now while this does bother me, it is not the focus at the moment.

What I would like to be able to do is get a count of records that are duplicates with the same `manifestNumber` but this time base that count off of how many have the field `originRemitStatus` as set to 1 based off the original group of `$unsentManifests`.

//Same Data and Expected Results//

From the fetch:

```
manifestNumber: 1234
originRemitStatus: null

manifestNumber: 1234
originRemitStatus: null

manifestNumber: 1234
originRemitStatus: 1

manifestNumber 9876
originRemit Status: null

manifestNumber 9876
originRemit Status: null

manifestNumber 4567
originRemit Status: null

manifestNumber 4567
originRemit Status: 1
```

Returned results:

- 1234 (1)
- 9876 (0)
- 4567 (1)

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - I believe I have included what I am trying to imagine, but not entirely sure. If you need further clarification, just let me know and I'll type more up above. Thanks again - Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Carrier_Manifest::select('manifestNumber')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(IF(originRemitStatus = 1, 1, 0)) count')
    ->groupBy('manifestNumber');
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?